# What does it mean to "bypass" a plasma relay or EPS conduit, etc.?

Tags: star-trek, technology

At various times in the Star Trek universe, somebody says they should bypass something like a plasma/EPS relay or conduit. What does such a "bypass" entail? Like, physically, what is happening? Is it ever established in-universe what the nature of these by-passes are?

Comment: I’m not sure, but I do know that even though it should take at least eight hours, Geordi will somehow get it done in two.

Comment: Wait I do know: physically, someone in the writer’s room has just hit copy and paste, and is right about to order a nice early lunch.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - The writers just used to write "*[Tech]*" when they needed a solution and one of their science consultants would fill in the gaps later.

Comment: Sometimes you also have to reverse polarity, or re-calibrate something.

Comment: @Dima - And don't get me started on the wide range of things that need to be decoupled

Comment: https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Technobabble

Answer (score 8):

Generally a "bypass" allows what normally flows through an object to flow through a different (occasionally temporary) substitute.  A highway bypass allows traffic to flow by a different route than the local traffic streets, a hyperspace bypass allows spaceships to skip over the inconvenient normal space by taking a shortcut through hyperspace.  A heart bypass allows blood to flow through a different route than the damaged artery or vein that it would normally go through, and so on.

A bypass relay in *Star Trek* would presumably allow electrical or other energy to take another route besides the one normally used (likely, so that the flow continues while the broken conduit is being repaired) in an analogous way to the way that electricity uses a modern [bypass](https://www.constantpowerservices.com/questions/6-what-does-a-bypass-switch-in-a-ups-system-do)

> A static bypass switch automatically and instantaneously transfers the
> load to the mains electricity supply when there’s an internal fault or
> failure with the UPS system.
>
> In effect, running on bypass the circumvents the UPS (i.e. rectifier,
> batteries, and inverter) and ensures power continuity while the UPS is
> fixed or swapped out.

A starship, being a vessel expected to operate away from port for lengthy periods and to experience battle damage, may have bypasses specially designed for ease of storage and wide compatibility.

Comment: Thanks! Is it established what the nature of these by-passes is? Are they pre-built, ready to be triggered into action? Or do they need to be installed on-the-fly by a crew, using some sort of customizable conduit? They seem to come into effect fairly quickly, but it also seems a little wild for so many by-passes just to be hanging around, on the ready for a flip of a switch somewhere.

Comment: Rerouting through a bypass, @user133469, takes precisely as long as the plot requires. Nothing more, nothing less. The more dire the situation, the closer the actual repair time takes to the engineer's original estimate.

Comment: @user133469: I'd presume many of them are pre-built physical lines that are either inactive, or active below their maximum capacity, and can be switched on in order to take over additional load, while the bypassed segment is meanwhile disabled. But who knows, maybe it also sometimes means some crewmembers of the Engineering department are connecting cables (and, favourite input interface for low-level things in the 24th century, placing isolinear chips into different slots) in some Jefferies tube. And if nothing else helps, a poor yellow-shirted Ensign might have to play live wire :(

Answer (score 3):

To further answer the question around what a physical bypass was and what it looked like we need to start back at the basic premise of a EPS/plasma conduit and then move forward into its potential usage around vessels and then what an in universe bypass might be.

Firstly we have to understand what the conduits are transporting and what they are used for.

The Memory Alpha Page on [EPS conduits](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Electro-plasma_system) states:

> The electro-plasma system (EPS for short, or more specifically the electro-plasma distribution network, the term preferred by engineers) was the primary form of energy distribution on starships.

> The technology was based on storing energy in a highly energetic plasma, "electro-plasma," and distributing it throughout the ship via plasma conduits, called EPS conduits. The system of conduits was also referred to as the plasma grid.

[Electro Plasma](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Electro-plasma)  is further explained to be:

> In high-power mechanics, electro-plasma was a super-energized plasma used to transfer energy from a central power source using plasma conduit transfer.

[Plasma](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Plasma) is further explained to be:

> Plasma is one of the four fundamental states of matter. To be more exact, plasma is an ionized gaseous state, which is commonly seen in an electrical arc.

In the real world, [Neon Lights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neon_sign) are examples of plasma conduits as they are:

> Electric signs lighted by long luminous gas-discharge tubes that contain rarefied neon or other gases.

Taking this items into account we can see that EPS conduits are transporting a highly charged gaseous material around the ship.

The movement of a material (unlike the movement of electricity) can be seen in First Contact where:

> Lieutenant Barclay found a length of copper tubing and suggested that it be used to replace that damaged warp plasma conduit. Commander La Forge approved, but noted that it would have to be reinforced with a nanopolymer.

[image: first contact plasma conduit]

Unlike electricity which would run along a copper wire, in this instance the plasma would be running through the copper tubing.

This process of running a material through a system can also be seen in this EPS manifold from Star Trek Enterprise. Which has input/output like devices on either side.

[image: enterprise]

EPS conduits are in effect arteries and veins that go though an entire ship transporting a gaseous substance. This network of tubes can be seen in this diagram from a Galaxy class vessel. (I believe shown by the fuzzy pink lines)

[image: conduits]

We can see from the above that any bypass would need to move a gaseous substances from one pipe network to another. While I don't believe any bypasses are shown on screen, any real world example of gas or water bypasses would by analogous.

The easiest example I can think of would be the hacking minigame from Biowares Bioshock were you need to move a liquid like substance from one location to another.

[image: hacking]

A bypass is fundamentally a tube that directs a substance around a damaged area. The pipe network already exists and the plasma is just being transferred down a different route, as would be done in real world gas or water installations.

The time taken to implement these bypasses would depend on what was broken and how it needed to be circumvented.

Using a real world analogue, old landline phones ran on copper wire. The phone in a house in the UK would connect to a box outside, this would connect to a box at the end of the street, this would connect to the exchange, which would then connect to a national trunk, this would then connect to a transatlantic cable. This would then connect to a national trunk, that would connect to an exchange, that would connect to a box, that would connect to a house, that would connect to a phone in America.

If there was any break in that line, you would need to bypass it. This could be done by just swapping a connection at an exchange/box termination, so you don't effect the individual connection to a house. If the cable to your house is broken, you may need to dig up the road to lay a new cable, which will take a lot more time. If the transatlantic cable is broken then that's a whole heap of work.

A Starfleet officer implementing a bypass, might just need to flick a switch, or he might need to lay miles of new piping that's up to whatever regulation code they follow.

Answer (score 1):

EPS is a short for [Electro-plasma system](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Electro-plasma_system) - click the link if you would like to know more - and in short it's a power delivery system, based on plasma.

Plasma is, if I remember correctly a gas of energetically charged particles - think Sun for example.

So if any element of the EPS fails it needs to be replaced or bypassed. Starfleet ships have one, sometimes two backup systems, so usually there is no need for bypass, unless damage is extensive or it delivers power to tertiary systems.

See ST:TNG episode "Genesis" to see in some detail how work on EPS conduits being done:

> Barclay and Geordi crawling along, Barclay carrying the equipment case. Barclay is crawling quickly and with great skill -- Geordi can barely keep up. They come to   a stop at a CORRODED PANEL that looks like it's been eaten away by acid.
>
> BARCLAY: Here we are. It looks like the conduit ruptured. No problem, I'll just           bypass it...
>
> Barclay opens a SECOND PANEL along the wall, and sets   the PANEL COVER on the floor. He reaches into the acideaten     panel and grabs hold of a CABLE, which FRITZES  with an ELECTRICAL FLASH for a moment. He begins to     insert the cable in the second wall panel, re-routing   it...
>
> As Barclay works, Geordi scans the acid-eaten panel     with his tricorder.

And in ST:VOY it is described, somewhat, what a EPS conduit bypass is:

> JANEWAY: Doctor, do you know anything about bypassing a power relay?
>
> EMH: Is it anything like a coronary bypass?
>
> JANEWAY: Actually, it is.
> Give me a hand. See this conduit? It's a power relay. It's circuits
> are burnt out. What we need to do is reconfigure the...

So we are given to understand that bypass is a procedure where damaged part of the EPS needs to be worked around to deliver power to the part of the ship or the system .

My understanding is it means literally to unspool a section of the conduit and plug it into two nearest to the damage points to go around damaged module or section of the conduit. Alternatively it may involve conduits AND a manifold placed in the corridor or jeffries tube next to a damaged one.